# How to implement Android mirroring application, using spydroid library and media projection?

Tags: android, video, rtp

I want know how to send my screen over RTP? Here is my approach.

First, I'm using media projection to capture my screen. Referenced url is http://mattsnider.com/video-recording-with-mediaprojectionmanager/

Second, I'm using and try to modify spydroid library, to stream my screen not camera view.

Referenced url is https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera

I've done screen capture using media projection. Here is some part of sample code.

```
private boolean drainEncoder() {
    mDrainHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrainEncoderRunnable);
    while (true) {
        int bufferIndex = mVideoEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mVideoBufferInfo, 0);

        if (bufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            // nothing available yet
            break;
        }
        else if (bufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
            if (mTrackIndex >= 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");
            }
            mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(mVideoEncoder.getOutputFormat());
            if (!mMuxerStarted && mTrackIndex >= 0) {
                mMuxer.start();
                mMuxerStarted = true;
            }
        }
        else if (bufferIndex < 0) {
            // not sure what's going on, ignore it
        }
        else {
            ByteBuffer encodedData = mVideoEncoder.getOutputBuffer(bufferIndex);
            if (encodedData == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("couldn't fetch buffer at index " + bufferIndex);
            }

            if ((mVideoBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                mVideoBufferInfo.size = 0;
            }

            if (mVideoBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                if (mMuxerStarted) {
                    encodedData.position(mVideoBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(mVideoBufferInfo.offset + mVideoBufferInfo.size);
                    mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mVideoBufferInfo);
                }
                else {
                    // muxer not started
                }
            }

            mVideoEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, false);

            if ((mVideoBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see,

`mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mVideoBufferInfo);`

If it possible to send encodedData via RTP then mirroring will work fine.

Here is spydroid code, VideoStream.Java

```
protected void encodeWithMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "Video encoded using the MediaRecorder API");

    // We need a local socket to forward data output by the camera to the packetizer
    createSockets();

    // Reopens the camera if needed
    destroyCamera();
    createCamera();

    // The camera must be unlocked before the MediaRecorder can use it
    unlockCamera();

    try {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(mVideoEncoder);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mRequestedQuality.resX, mRequestedQuality.resY);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mRequestedQuality.framerate);

        // The bandwidth actually consumed is often above what was requested 
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate((int) (mRequestedQuality.bitrate * 0.8));

        // We write the ouput of the camera in a local socket instead of a file !           
        // This one little trick makes streaming feasible quiet simply: data from the camera
        // can then be manipulated at the other end of the socket
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mSender.getFileDescriptor());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConfNotSupportedException(e.getMessage());
    }

    // This will skip the MPEG4 header if this step fails we can't stream anything :(
    InputStream is = mReceiver.getInputStream();
    try {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4];
        // Skip all atoms preceding mdat atom
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            while (is.read() != 'm') ;
            is.read(buffer, 0, 3);
            if (buffer[0] == 'd' && buffer[1] == 'a' && buffer[2] == 't') break;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't skip mp4 header :/");
        stop();
        throw e;
    }

    // The packetizer encapsulates the bit stream in an RTP stream and send it over the network
    mPacketizer.setDestination(mDestination, mRtpPort, mRtcpPort);
    mPacketizer.setInputStream(mReceiver.getInputStream());
    mPacketizer.start();

    mStreaming = true;
}
```

Can anyone advise me? Some more information how to modify spydroid library to send mirroring data?

Comment: have you got it working?

Comment: yeah I got it but have a some problem.